# Whats wrong this this JS program

Tags: javascript

```
var comments = {};
comments.data = ["Good!", "Bye", "I hate it..."];
comments.print = function() {
    this.data.forEach(function(el) {
    console.log(comments.print()); 
    });
}
```

It is supposed to print the data which is inside the comments ("Good!", "Bye", "I hate it..."). Comments is an object. I could have defined the function inside the curly braces but I wanted to do it with different syntax.

Comment: Infinite loop? Change `console.log(comments.print());` to `console.log(el); `

Comment: It'll go in loop. accessing function before defining it completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its running in recursion. Its calling itself. So its infinite. Replace comments.print() with el

Try this:

```
var comments = {};
comments.data = ["Good!", "Bye", "I hate it..."];
comments.print = function() {
    comments.data.forEach(function(el) {
    console.log(el); 
    });
}
comments.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling print() into your print() function, so this may cause an infinite loop. I guess at each loop you want to log "Good", then "Bye", then "I hate it", so you just have to call `el` and not comments wich is the whole object ?

```js
var comments = {};
comments.data = ["Good!", "Bye", "I hate it..."];
comments.print = function() {
    this.data.forEach(function(el) {
      console.log(el); 
    });
}

comments.print() ;
```